# Trying to create an object from an interface

Tags: java, enums, interface

My assignment for uni has clear instructions and they want me to create a dish by utilizing an interface. But I can't even create a proper test-dish without an error, what am I doing wrong?

DishTypes as enum:

(This can't be changed at all)

```
public enum DishType {
    STARTER, MAIN_DISH, DESSERT, OTHER;
}
```

Interface Dish:

(For the interface the classes and names can't be changed/deleted as per instructions, only their body and return-statements)

```
public interface Dish {
    String getName();

    double getBasePrice();

    DishType getDishType();

    static Dish createDish(String name, double basePrice, DishType type) {
       return createDish(name,basePrice,type);
    }
}
```

And here is the class I created on my own to be able to implement a dish:

```
public class DishImplementation implements Dish {

    public String name;
    private double basePrice;
    private DishType type;

    public DishImplementation(String name, double basePrice, DishType type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.basePrice = basePrice;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public double getBasePrice() {
        return basePrice;
    }

    @Override
    public DishType getDishType() {
        return type;
    }
```

Now if I try to create a test-dish using my Test class I always get an error:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dish d1 = Dish.createDish("a",1.0, DishType.MAIN_DISH);
        System.out.println(d1.getName());
    }
}
```

How do I get the console to actually show me the name of my test-dish?

Comment: Your `Dish.createDish` static method calls itself endlessly its called "recursion" :) In general if you say that you "always get an error" - please add also the error itself in the question. Usually in java errors are pretty detailed and include the line that has produced  an error as well the exception type (what error exactly has happened)

Comment: Instead of calling same method again, call constructor of DishImplementation.

Comment: By the way, [« Course »](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/course) would be a better name for `DishType`. And `createDish` method could be simply be `create`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your createDish(...) method should return an object instead of recursively   invoking itself.

Here is how you'd do it.

```
public interface Dish {
    String getName();

    double getBasePrice();

    DishType getDishType();

    static Dish createDish(String name, double basePrice, DishType type) {
       return new DishImplementation(name,basePrice,type);
    }
}
```